# Codeigniter server error when the URL contains any controller or method with arguments on a hosting service

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, web-hosting, htdocs

I did develop my website on localhost using codeigniter framework then I got a domain name and hosting service from www.web.com.

I upload my website to folder htdocs in root folder of the server.
This is the structure:

- /

  - cgi-bin
  - htdocs

    - application
    - system
    - js
    - css
    - img
    - index.php
    - .htaccess

suppose that my domain is **www.example.com** and it is pointing to htdocs folder.

When I type **www.example.com** it opens my home page successfully without errors.

But when I try to open any other page such **www.example.com/products** or **www.example.com/products/browse_product/2** it loads the page successfully but at the end of every page this error always appears

[ERROR SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACxBz.png)

My .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: can you add your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: does it work without htaccess file

Comment: No it doesn't load any other controller without .htaccess

Comment: @MohamedHana please add server logs

Comment: I don't know where to find server logs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solve the problem by performing this:

/* config.php file */

```
$config['index_page'] = ''; 
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

/* routes.php file */

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home"; 
$route[''] = "home/index"; 
$route['home'] = "home/index"; 
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

/* main .htaccess file */

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```